# Employee vs Employe Which Is More Correct/Common

Tags: orthography

It is always interesting when a word has multiple accepted spellings. I'm wondering what people here have to say on this particular word.

Comment: Can you cite any evidence that ***Employe*** even has any *currency* (let alone *credibility*)?

Comment: Employee (also employe), 
noun:
One who is employed by another (AHD) :http://www.thefreedictionary.com/employe.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know if you would consider dictionary.com to be credible, but http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/employe is a thing, as is https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/employe. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/employee lists 'employe' as a variant.

Comment: - 1 You don't know which is more common? Which form people consider "correct"?  I find that very hard to believe. Now, if you had asked what happened to "employe" or why one form was/is preferred that *might* provoke some interesting answers.

Comment: Maybe @linuxdan has been a lone-wolf entrepreneur living under a rock and raised by the French. In Chico, CA. Okay, maybe he's just a troll.

Comment: Which is more common: a lone-wolf entrepreneur living under a rock and raised by the French, or anything else ever?

Comment: Like I said in @Josh61's answer, "Damn outliers."

Comment: Just a chance for most  of  us to learn something new!! Thanks @linuxdan

Comment: @linuxdan: Yes, I think dictionary.reference is a perfectly credible source. So far as I can see, *all* its content is culled from "established" dictionaries   (though they do claim to have their [own team of experienced lexicographers](http://content.dictionary.com/). I was surprised to see that entry, but consulting the full OED I find it is indeed listed. As a ***North American*** usage, with the caveat that ***Employee** is far more common in contemporary use, but **employe** is the preferred spelling in certain publications.*

Comment: ...note that you really should have included those definitions in the original question, rather than saving them to be brandished "in defence" after the fully-expected **WTF?** reaction.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen "employe" here in the US on occasion, but I've always regarded it as a misspelling.  If nothing else it just look weird.

Comment: Note that there is a natural tendency to prefer the double "ee" when a word ends with an "e" sound, since it eliminates the question of whether the "e" should be pronounced or not, when "sounding out" the word.

Comment: https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/opinions/1988/01/10/stop-me-before-i-spell-again/e1cbf9e9-8f14-4c22-8244-637ddc5129ae/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[Employe](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/employe)*** is a rare dated alternative spelling of the more common  ***employee*** (AHD)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20employe&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20employe%3B%2Cc0): *an employe*. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20employe%2Can%20employee&year_start=1870&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20employe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20employee%3B%2Cc0): *an employee vs an employe*

> - From French employé.
>     *Employe (plural employes).*
> - 1920, Conference proceedings of the National Electric Light Association Convention, National Independent Meat Packers Association, the University of Georgia College of Agriculture, page 103:
>     For that clerk, in the eyes of the people who come to you for service, *is not merely an employe.*
> - 1935, Education Digest, page 16:
>     As soon as a qualified substitute can be obtained, he should, upon *the request of an employe* recommend him for release from his contract.
> - 1922, Lila Bell Acheson Wallace and De Witt Wallace, The Readers Digest, The Readers Digest Association, page 86:
>     Bring the same relationship we used to enjoy in the firm of 50 years ago > > - when the employe used to kick the boss's door open and say: 'Joe, I just discovered [...]'.
> - 1859, Transactions of the Gulf Coast Association of Geological Societies, the Chicago Homeopathic Medical Society, page 156:
>     In his endeavor to justify a radical action, the employe often carries his grievance so far that an element of the ridiculous enters into his arguments [...].

(Wiktionary)

From Etymonline

***[-ee](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-ee&searchmode=none)***

> - ***word-forming element in legal English (and in imitation of it), representing the Anglo-French -é ending of past participles used as nouns.*** As these sometimes were coupled with agent nouns in -or, the two suffixes came to be used as a pair to denote the initiator and the recipient of an action.

***[Employee](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=employee&allowed_in_frame=0):***

> - "person employed," 1850, mainly in U.S. use, from employ + -ee. ***Formed on model of French employé.***

Comment: I declare this usage to be a typo! :P Damn outliers.

Comment: @Josh61 thanks for actually providing an answer, rather than ridiculing my ability to spell, or do proper research for myself.

Comment: OED make no mention of it being dated, obsolete, archaic, or whatever. And their two most recent citations are 1979 & 2006 - they don't normally include such recent usages for words which have declined significantly over time. My guess it was always "rare", but has stubbornly refused to curl up and die.